# nunit test for parameterized constructor

Tags: constructor, nunit

Am asked to test a parameterized constructor.Dont understand why its necessary. Share you thoughts.Any solution please share.
Below is the code,

```
 public class CaseItemReport
{
    #region Members

    #region core referral members
    private long _ReportId;
    private long _CaseIdItem;
    private CaseReport _CaseReport;
    private DateTime _CreationDate;
    private int _Accuracy;
    private int _Severity;
    private int _Visibility;
    #endregion

    #region report result members
    private ReportResult _Result;
    private long _Reason;
    #endregion


                #region Constructors
         public CaseItemReport(CaseReport cr)
    {
        this._CaseReport = cr;
        this.ReportId = -1;
        this.CaseIdItem = cr.CaseIdUser;
        this.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
        this.Accuracy = 0;
        this.Severity = 0;
        this.Visibility = 0;
        this.Reason = 0;
        this.Result = ReportResult.ACTION;
    }


   public class CaseReport : BusinessObjectBase
{
    public CaseReport()
    {

    }

    public string BreadCrumb { get; set; }
    public bool CanAutomate { get; set; }
    public long CaseIdUser { get; set; }
    //public Consequence Consequence { get; set; }
    public DateTime EarliestItemStartDate { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddressFrom { get; set; }
    public string FilterName { get; set; }
    public bool IsEMR { get; set; }
    public bool IsMemberLevelReferral { get; set; }
    public bool IsPolice { get; set; }
    public bool IsSheriff { get; set; }
    public bool IsValidReport
```

I need to write testcase for the constructor CaseItemReport.Please help

Comment: Then start writing. whats the problem in writing test Case for constructor ?

Comment: finding difficulty in checking constructor with parameter.

Comment: in above code you just have 1 constructor. you need to make an object and  by passing Caserport to it. Then you will just verify the CaseItemReport that it is in consistent state.

Comment: How do i pass casereport to constructor object.This is the problem am facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Test
{
CaseReport cr;
//assign some values to cr.

 CaseItemReport caseItemReport (cr);

// now verify that all values are set and in working condition or not.

}
```

I hope you got the point

Comment: [Test]
          public void CaseItemReportTest()
        {
            CaseReport cr;
            cr.BreadCrumb = "New";
            cr.CanAutomate = false;
            cr.CaseIdUser = 999;
           CaseItemReport caseItemreport = new CaseItemReport(cr);
           Assert.AreEqual(caseItemreport.ReportId, -1);
           Assert.AreEqual(caseItemreport.CreationDate, DateTime.Now);
           Assert.AreEqual(caseItemreport.Accuracy, 0);
           Assert.AreEqual(caseItemreport.Severity, 0);
       }
    }
}

Comment: also check values of CaseReport